# I am getting error when I try to execute script with rest assured framework for API automation. Please guide me to resolve the same

Tags: java, api

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.restassured.common.mapper.resolver.ObjectMapperResolver.isJakartaEEInClassPath()Z
at rest.assured@5.1.1/io.restassured.config.ObjectMapperConfig.newJakartaEEObjectMapperFactoryOrNullIfNotInClasspath(ObjectMapperConfig.java:265)
at rest.assured@5.1.1/io.restassured.config.ObjectMapperConfig.(ObjectMapperConfig.java:60)
at rest.assured@5.1.1/io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
at rest.assured@5.1.1/io.restassured.RestAssured.(RestAssured.java:422)
at GoogleplaceProject/Basics.Api.main(Api.java:17)

Comment: Check for incompability in your dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

it can not find method.you should check you code or jar.